# Heroku CI - monorepo with docker

Tags: git, docker, heroku, heroku-ci

I have one repository for both backend and frontend that Im trying to deploy.
I also have two docker containers, one for my backend and one for my frontend.
Since Heroku app can only have one web process, how can I use heroku.yml to deploy my backend and frontend?

Comment: When you say backend/frontend are you trying to deploy say a`client` and `server` (like node\express) or is it a database?

Comment: Yes. My frontend is vue/nuxt and my backend is node/express. thanks

Comment: I am not too familiar with `vue` but what I have done (`react` & `node`) is built it into a single image that I deploy to Heroku. I don't think there is any other way around it?